# Computing determinants

Tags: matrices

While computing a determinant I know I can do the following:

a) factor out common constants (and in doings so multiply the determinant by the constant)

b) add rows (or columns) or a constant times a row to another row.

c) exchange rows (or columns) (and I change signs every time I perform such an operation)

In doing these row operations, if I reduce my matrix to an upper triangular matrix then the determinant just becomes the product of elements along the diagonal.

But then if I start with an invertible matrix, I know that it is row equivalent to identity. Then shouldn't the determinant of every invertible matrix be 1? this isn't the case though.

Comment: "factor out common constant" means you have to multiply them to the determinant.

Comment: Yes. I am sorry I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"factor out common constant" means you have to multiply them to the determinant.: $2I$ is row equivalent to $I$, but it doesn't mean $det(2I)=det(I)$, since you factor out the $2$ (for $n$ times), so at the end
$$det(2I)=2^ndet(I)=2^n$$
If you can get the identity matrix without using the a), then you get
$$det(A)=\pm det(I)=\pm 1$$
where the sign is decided by c)

Comment: Ah thank you. I see the flaw in my logic now.

Answer (score 1):

Over any commutative ring $R$, $A$ is an invertible matrix if and only if $\det A$ is a unit in $R$. This is is because $\,\det(AB)=\det A\det B$.

It only means that, if $R$ is a field, $\det A\neq 0$. If $R=\mathbf Z$, $\det A=\pm1$, &c.